# JavaScript Class Syntax: Static Data Members

Tags: javascript, class, static

I cannot find any information about how one defines static data members in JavaScript using the (relatively new) class syntax. Is it even possible? Please see the following example code:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Default Name for each Instance';
    // staticData1 = 'Static Data 1'; // syntax error
    let staticData2 = 'Static Data 2'; // undefined outside
  }

  doSthSpecial() {
    console.log('Executing a method from instance "' + this.name + '"');
  }

  static doSthStatic() {
    console.log('Executing a method that does the same for each instance of "Foo"');
  }
}

foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.name);
foo.doSthSpecial();
Foo.doSthStatic();
// The problematic case:
console.log(Foo.staticData2);
```

Comment: This is a stage 2 proposition, no? So, it's not standardized. I'm solving for this by using [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/). Edit: @shaochuancs explains it well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Foo.staticData2 = 'Static Data 2'` to define static data member of class Foo, after Foo itself is defined.

According to ES6, there is no static property inside class definition, only static method.

In ES7, there is a proposal on static field definition, currently it is at stage 2 (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields). Good new is: Babel has supported this proposal (https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).

Comment: Okay, first point: That's a pitty because it cannot be done in (anonymous) class expressions like `return class { /*...*/ }` which are pretty nice otherwise. Second point: great, so i am looking forward to future version of the standard.

Comment: Actually, if you use Babel to transform ES6/ES7 code,  the stage 2 proposal syntax on static field can be used right now.

Answer (score 4):

I found a work-around that comes quite close to what is asked. One can use a *computed property* ("get method") and make it static. Then there is no need for the "()" function/method call syntax and it is available without any instance of the class. May be a little less efficient though. 
Example:

```
let Foo = class {
  static get staticData() {
    return 'Static Data';
  }
}

console.log(Foo.staticData);
```

Answer (score 3):

This works, and it keeps the messy details inside the class.

```
class cExample
{  
  static init_index() {
     cExample.index = 0;
  }   

  static get_index() {
     return ++cExample.index;
  }   
}

cExample.init_index();

example = new cExample();
console.log(cExample.get_index());  // 1
example = new cExample();
console.log(cExample.get_index());  // 2
example = new cExample();
console.log(cExample.get_index());  // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround that works for me, not the most elegant but at least until ES7 is to locate the static members after the class:

```
class Field {

  constructor(index) {
    this.index = index;
  }

  getName(name) {
    return this.name;
  }
}

Field.DISPLAY_AS_TEXT = 2001;
Field.DISPLAY_AS_BARCODE = 2002;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize statics in the constructor:

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    if (Foo.myStatic === undefined) Foo.myStatic = 'XXX';
    // or if appropriate
    Foo.myStatic = Foo.myStatic || 'XXX';
    // or the ES2020
    Foo.myStatic = Foo.myStatic ?? 'XXX';
  }
}
```